# Captcha Image Nominations

Tags: feature-request, design

According to the [Top 7](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), we need to select a CAPTCHA image.

So please submit your proposals as answers to this question.

Comment: An image with a Zombie might be appropriate here. "NO ZOMBIES!".

Answer (score 6):

- **One of us?**

[image]

Comment: I like it... but... would we have a copyright problem on our hands?

Comment: SO uses one from Flight of the Concords http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bgY8lQMFy4

Answer (score 3):

*"Sorry but bots aren't on the guest list"*

[image: The Unix Gang]

Comment: Ok this would be even better if we could have these guys dressed like it's a black tie event, and we added a *bearded human*.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** I originally posted this on [Ubuntu S.E.](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com), but it seemed like it was too 'geeky' for them because Ubuntu targets people just getting started with Linux.

---

Here is a little something I started with the model I got [here](http://www.katorlegaz.com/3d_models/miscellaneous/0167/index.php):

*Note: I used Blender on Linux to create this, so it fits quite well :)*

[image]

Maybe we can put a funny phrase on the sign like "Penguins Only" or something... ideas are welcome.

Comment: @George could you do one of these with the BSD Daemon too? and maybe the OpenBSD Fish

Comment: @George also maybe have the sign say "Humans and Penguins only."

Comment: Ideally the sign would show the captcha, but I don't think recaptcha is going to support that :)

Comment: @xeno: Maybe, if you can find a free Blender model for them.

Comment: @xenoterracide: "Humans, Penguins, Fish, Platypus and Daemons only"

Comment: @Maciej we should take that other picture I found and do something like that.

Answer (score 2):

[image: useless use of cat]

(from [GirlieMac](http://www.flickr.com/photos/girliemac/)'s [HTTP Status Cats](http://www.flickr.com/photos/girliemac/sets/72157628409467125/))