# Error image nominations

Tags: support, design

The [404 page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/404), [error page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/error) and [captcha page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/captcha) have very generic images.

There have been proposals for [404 images](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/404-image-nominations) and [captcha images](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118/captcha-image-nominations) before.

This is a call for **error image nominations**.

Furthermore, the text on these pages should include [standard unix error messages](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5646/libiberty/strerror.c):

- 404: `No such file or directory`, of course
- captcha: `Permission denied`?
- error: `I/O error`?

Comment: good idea -- something nice and Unix-y!

Comment: Didn't we already do this a long time ago?

Comment: oh right... and you mention it. It's been ignored by the SO team. Since they have complete control over that, I have no opinion, it would be ignored anyways.

Comment: @xenoterracide: There were previous threads about 404 and captcha, I started a new one about error, hoping that people would submit ideas. Once the community has made some kind of decision, we can start bugging the team (Jin?) to implement it.

Comment: Oh boy... does this mean that [picture of Tux in front of the computer](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120/404-image-nominations/121#121) has a chance?

Answer (score 2):

I'd really like this on the [offline page](http://sstatic.net/unix/app_offline.htm):

[image: /dev/nul]

(By [apswartz](http://www.flickr.com/photos/apswartz/), from the [Unix gallery on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/groups/unix))

Why I like it: the slightly fuzzy look (as if there was maintenance going on); the unix theme (`/dev/null`); the capitalization and lack of a second `L` (that's what the maintenance should be fixing).

Answer (score 2):

[image: useless use of cat]

(from [GirlieMac](http://www.flickr.com/photos/girliemac/)'s [HTTP Status Cats](http://www.flickr.com/photos/girliemac/sets/72157628409467125/))

Answer (score -1):

I'm confused, why would "standard unix error messages" link to something inside gcc?

Captcha should not be "Permission denied", because it's not denied yet. From that page you linked to I think "Connection reset by peer" is more suitable.

Lots of other (not better) error messages can also be used for the error page: "Host is down", "Network is down", "Network is unreachable".

Comment: The link was the first google hit for a list of `strerror` strings. I think “Permission denied” is ok because retrying with a captcha is analogous to retrying with sudo. I don't like having a network error message here because there's a risk of confusion with an actual network error.

Comment: Put an interrogation mark after the funny error messages. This should be enough to convey the idea that those are not real error messages.